# ASP.NET Cookie Expires value resets on Response.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I have a script that reads a form and puts some info into a cookie:

```
Dim oCookie as HttpCookie
oCookie = New HttpCookie("authInfo")
Select Case oResult
Case "No ClientID", "No Password", "No PracType", "No Encrypt", "CRC Mismatch"
    oCookie.Values.Add("LoggedIn", "False")
    oCookie.Values.Add("OnSupport", "False")
Case "Client Can Update"
    oCookie.Values.Add("LoggedIn", "True")
    oCookie.Values.Add("OnSupport", "True")
Case "Client Cannot Update"
    oCookie.Values.Add("LoggedIn", "True")
    oCookie.Values.Add("OnSupport", "False")
End Select
oCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(oCookie)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
```

The time is properly set right before it redirects, but when I try to print out that value this way (I have also tried `Dim oCol as HttpCookieCollection = Request.Cookies`, but I get the same result):

```
Response.Output.WriteLine(Request.Cookies("authInfo").Expires.ToString)
```

The time is always reset `"01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM"`.  Am I missing something that prevents the cookie from holding its `Expires` value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Request.Cookies and Response.Cookies and use of the common cookie object makes of an intuative idiom but in fact a Request cookie and a Response cooke are quite different.

When you assign a Cookie in the response a Set-Cookie header gets added to the output and that will contain not only the value but also the path and the expiries value.

However when the browser sends the cookie back to the server in another request it simply includes the cookie name and value.  It does not send path or expires info.

Hence these properties are meaningless when using the Request.Cookies collection.

Comment: So how, if it is possible, do I preserve the Expires value?

Comment: @Anders: are you changing the cookie value?  If so why would it not get a new expires value?  If not why are you trying to set it again, you need only create the cookie once.

Comment: No, check the code above. I am creating a new cookie, setting 3 values (including the Expires; 2 otherwise).

Comment: @Anders: The browser will preserve it and will terminate the cookie once it has expired.  Do you need to read the expires value in a subsequent request?  If you so you will need store it in some other persistant storage serverside.

Comment: You don't need to preserve the value.  It staysconstant until hte cookie expires.  Also FYI you really shouldn't be passing sql queries around in cookies.  Execute the sql and get the value and store that in a cookie, but not the query itself.  It's not that hard for other people to view those.

Comment: @ Chris: I am not storing queries in the cookies, where do you see that?

Comment: @Anthony: I think I'll encode a string containing all the values I need then pass that along instead of trying to muck around with this issue. Thanks for your insight on how Request/Response cookies work and differ.

Comment: Never mind, I've been using sql too long and saw select case and thought that was an sql statement.  Geeze I need to go home.  :)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread and probably @Anders has moved on to bigger and better things from here. Still, I happened to stumble upon this after facing the same problem while trying to retain Office 365 authentication cookies in my current HttpContext. Suffice to say, that @AnthonyWJones' answer clarified a lot of intuitions I had about cookies. This is for anyone like me who must have come upon this thread and despite the information exchanged was not able to figure out a roundabout for sustaining the cookie expiration date. 
Here is what I finally attempted: 
1. Before the cookie (whose expiry date is necessary) is added to the HttpResponse, I persisted its expiration date and domain in my DB.
2. The cookie can then be added to the Response with its basic properties intact such as "Name" and "Value".
3. Once the cookie is retrieved from the request, I constructed a new cookie with the domain and expiration dates obtained from the DB and the rest of the properties as is.
I was then able to use those cookies for initiating further requests to the target site.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into such an issue when the initial request came from a different domain.
make sure you also add the domain for the cookie.

Comment: I tried that; no avail. I am testing on localhost right now, do I need include the port as part of the domain (ie localhost:12345 instead of just localhost)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for the expiration date you can add it to the cookie value collection. Then retrieve it and do the check.